# Embeddable editor for scripting language

Tags: scripting, code-editor

I'm looking for a good editor that is embeddable into application (using either QT or GTK toolkit if needed), and would allow editing of scripts with:

- Code completion
- Inline documentation / context sensitive documentation
- Syntax highlighting

Any language is fine (Scheme, Lua, Python etc.) as long as I can get good - noob friendly editor for it which I can embed into my application (so licence is also a concern, I'd hate to have to licence whole project as GPL and AGPL - I'd like to keep project on MIT/BSD license)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scintilla is made to be embedded. And, as far as I remember, works with GTK and QT. But it needs probably a bit of customization in order to get Code completion and Inline documentation / context sensitive documentation to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work, but http://www.ubuntugeek.com/gummi-simple-latex-editor-written-in-pythongtk.html. It seems to be an open-source, MIT-licenced LaTeX editor. I haven't used it before, nor embedded it, but in theory you could embed it (unless of course n00bs don't know latex...)

Comment: noobs don't know latex but thanks anyway might be very usefull in future.